# Updating / adding Cellstyle to existing in r xlsx

Tags: r, excel, apache-poi, xlsx, rjava

Somehow the function `xlsx::getCellStyle` does not work as expected. Regarding [THIS](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getCellStyle--) it should return a Cellstyle Obj. Yet it returns something of class "rJava". Therefore I cant use it to update the Cellstyle.

So in this example, we first `Fill` a cell in blue, then I want to later update the Cellstyle and add a `Border` to it. (I know I could add two styles at once. This question however is about updating to an existing Cellstyle)

#### Code

```
filename = "df.xlsx"
df <- data.frame(Var="Entry")
xlsx::write.xlsx(df,file = filename)

wb     <- xlsx::loadWorkbook(filename)
sheets <- xlsx::getSheets(wb)
sheet  <- sheets[[1]]                  # get specific sheet
rows   <- xlsx::getRows(sheet)         # get rows
cells  <- xlsx::getCells(rows)         # get cells

fillStyle <- xlsx::CellStyle(wb) + xlsx::Fill()
xlsx::setCellStyle(cells[[4]],fillStyle) #add fillstyle to cell with "Entry"
xlsx::saveWorkbook(wb,filename)

wb     <- xlsx::loadWorkbook(filename)
sheets <- xlsx::getSheets(wb)
sheet  <- sheets[[1]]                  # get specific sheet
rows   <- xlsx::getRows(sheet)         # get rows
cells  <- xlsx::getCells(rows)         # get cells

oldStyle <- xlsx::getCellStyle(cells[[4]])
newStyle <- oldStyle + xlsx::Border()

xlsx::setCellStyle(cells[[4]],newStyle)
xlsx::saveWorkbook(wb,filename)
```

Comment: Regarding "Somehow the function `xlsx::setCellStyle` does not work as expected." Are you sure you don't mean `xlsx::getCellStype`? `setCellStyle` returns a void.

Comment: I edited my question. Its `xlsx::getCellStyle`. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like the r xlsx library is an incomplete wrapper of Apache POI that doesn't necessarily reflect the latest POI behavior or documentation. https://github.com/dragua/xlsx/tree/master/R https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsxjars/index.html mentions xlsxjars corresponds to POI 3.10.1. You may want to ask your question on the xlsx R project website to see if an R wrapper for POI's `getCellStyle` is needed here.